# B2C Identity Experience Framework is taking a lot of time to reflect changes for Custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Lately, in the Identity Experience Framework, after uploading the policies successfully, the changes are not getting reflected immediately.

Has something changed?
Can we check somewhere, which version/timestamp of TrustFrameworkExtensions policy is getting used or something on similar line?

Currently the only way I can check which version is getting loaded is by setting a default value to a dummy parameter (and incrementing it each time) and using it in selfAssertion(for display purpose).

But this is serving me different versions (of dummy parameter in self assert), which is even more confusing.

Thanks,
Shridhar

PS:

1. Changes are reflected after wait of 5-10 mins.
2. I thought it was my browser caching the response. But then I opened developer tools and disabled my cache. It still did not work.

Comment: Did you set DeploymentMode="Development" at the top of each file? Otherwise it'll be caching policies. In production you should of course set it to Production.

Comment: Yes, we have that set in each of the RelyingParty policy files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - this is a known problem.

I believe Microsoft changed the policy caching to 15 minutes.

Comment: So is there a way around it or a way to know which version we are using?

Comment: Not that I'm aware - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1056470/aad-b2c-lag-after-custom-policy-upload

Comment: Thanks for this. This is strange and concerning behavior from B2C.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has documented that the caching default delay is up to 30 minutes for the custom policies. This is documented in the best practices.

"Azure AD B2C relies on caching to deliver performance to your end users. When you deploy a custom policy using whatever method, expect a delay of up to 30 minutes for your users to see the changes."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/best-practices#operations